# Location lingo update from head unit to iPhone app

Tags: ios, location, lingo

Head unit sends location lingo information/update. How does the iOS/iPhone app handle this update.

My app otherwise handles the location by using GPS info using CLLocationManager. But when the head unit is sending the location lingo, what is the way to read those updates.

Googled a lot but not much luck :(

Thanks!